# How to get \% in paste0()?

Tags: r, latex

I'm trying to generate some Latex code using R's `paste0()`. In order to print a percent sign, I need a single backslash in front of it, i.e., the result should be something like `$95\%$`. However, `paste0()` will not let me add a single backslash.

- `paste0(95, "%")` - Gives `"95%"`, which is of course useless for Latex.
- `paste0(95, "\%")` - Will throw `Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\%"`
- `paste0(95, "\\%")` - Will output BOTH backslashes, i.e., `"95\\%"`. But I only want **one**.

[In this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430376/escaping-symbol-when-passed-as-a-string-from-r-chunk-to-knitr), it says `paste0()` with `\\%` will output `\%`, but that is not the case for me. Any idea what's going on?

I'm using R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt).

EDIT: Solutions using `cat()` work in the console, but are not displayed in an R Markdown/Quarto document, e.g. when using the following inline code:

```
`r cat("95\\%")`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at `cat(paste0(95, "\\%"))`. By default `print()` will escape special characters with slashes. If you use `cat()` you will see the "real" value without any escaping.

Comment: You don't need the `cat` when knitting. That cat just shows you what's "really" there in the console. You need `\`r paste0(95, "\\%")\`` in your latex document.

Comment: Oh dang, I was certain that I had tried that and it didn't work. Now it works just fine - must have been a different mistake before. Seems like I was stupid *shakes head

Answer (score 1):

I use `glue`

```
library(glue)

glue("95\\%")

95\%
```

We can also generate the strings dinamically:

```
value <- 95

glue("{value}\\%")


95\%
```